# What does cleaning your house / uniform do in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

In Die2Nite, you're given the option to `Clean and Tidy My House` and `Clean Dirty Uniform` once everyday. What do these two options do - do they contribute to your success in any way or are they just there as something else you can do?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a distinction for it, much like there is one for working on construction a certain amount, or not using drugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They seem to do the same as the two buttons when the horde attacks. You know, where you can hide under your blankets, scream in agony and whatever more. They do absolutely nothing.

It gives me something to do when I get back from a hard minute at work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it does nothing also, but maybe if you do it long enough you get a decoration point.

P.S. I love to not wash my uniform.