# "Consider the lily" while scavenging?

Tags: die2nite

I was scavenging earlier, and when the timer got to 0, it switched to "Consider the lily" for about 5 seconds instead of "Next auto search".

[image: Consider the lily]

I assume this is just an easter egg or joke. Or does it actually do something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably flavor text showed while the browser asks the server about what you managed to find in your latest autosearch :)

Comment: Yep, it shows a random text for 5 seconds after the auto search is finished.

Answer (score 4):

As with many [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13214/what-does-cleaning-your-house-uniform-do-in-die2nite) [features](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13288/two-choices-when-a-town-is-under-attack) in Die2Nite, this text serves no in-game purpose other than to add a touch of humanization to your poor, doomed character.